# Rails paginate existing array of ActiveRecord results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination, thinking-sphinx, will-paginate

I generally use will_paginate for the pagination in my app, but have hit a stumbler on my search feature. I'm using Thinking Sphinx for doing my full-text search, which returns results paginated. The problem I'm having is that after I've received the results from Thinking Sphinx, I need to merge them with some other results and re-order them.

Once I've finished processing them I have an Array of results that is very different from the original from TS. As there could be 1000+ results in this Array Pagination is a necessity. The problem is that I can't figure out how to get will_paginate to play with an existing array.

I've done some research and it seems the only solutions to this problem are from several years ago and are based around the old built-in Paginator class. The most recent one I could find that makes use of will_paginate was from devchix from mid-2007: http://www.devchix.com/2007/07/23/will_paginate-array/comment-page-1/ - I've given this a go but it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Are there any current methods for applying pagination (preferably via will_paginate) for existing arrays of AR results?

Comment: Just to clarify, it's only the Pagination bit I'm having trouble with - everything else is fine.

Many thanks! :)

Comment: checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8407304/445908

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official will_paginate wiki](http://wiki.github.com/mislav/will_paginate/) links to this, albeit from 2008:

http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2008/06/how-to-use-will_paginate-with-non-activerecord-collectionarray/