# Ruby on Rails will_paginate an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I was wondering if someone could explain how to use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) on an array of objects?

For example, on my site I have an opinion section where users can rate the opinions. Here's a method I wrote to gather the users who have rated the opinion:

```
def agree_list
  list = OpinionRating.find_all_by_opinion_id(params[:id])
  @agree_list = []
  list.each do |r|
    user = Profile.find(r.profile_id)
    @agree_list << user
  end
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Having come here from a Google search for "rails paginate array", I wanted to share with other visitors that [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) is the rails pagination alternative that I settled on. Handles arrays elegantly.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

[will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) 3.0 is designed to take advantage of the new `ActiveRecord::Relation` in Rails 3, so it defines `paginate` only on relations by default. It can still work with an array, but you have to tell rails to require that part.

In a file in your `config/initializers` (I used `will_paginate_array_fix.rb`), add this

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

Then you can use on arrays

```
my_array.paginate(:page => x, :per_page => y)
```

Comment: This helped but it doesn't show the pagination in the view properly.

Comment: can someone tell me - how we will render it in view? ---   @array = my_array.paginate(:page => x, :per_page => y)                                                                                                               <%= will_paginate @array%>

Comment: @Robbie Guilfoyle my_array.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1) 

This fixed the pagination for me :)

Answer (score 9):

You could use `Array#from` to simulate pagination, but the real problem here is that you shouldn't be using `Array` at all.

This is what **[ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)** are made for. You should read that guide carefully, there is a lot of useful stuff you will need to know if you're developing Rails applications.

Let me show you a better way of doing the same thing:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opinion_ratings
  has_many :opinions, :through => :opinion_ratings
end

class Opinion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opinion_ratings
end

class OpinionRating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :opinion
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

It's important that your database schema is following the proper naming conventions or all this will break. Make sure you're creating your tables with **[Database Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)** instead of doing it by hand.

These associations will create helpers on your models to make searching much easier. Instead of iterating a list of OpinionRatings and collecting the users manually, you can make Rails do this for you with the use of `named_scope` or `scope` depending on whether you're using Rails 2.3 or 3.0. Since you didn't specify, I'll give both examples. Add this to your OpinionRating class:

**2.3**

```
named_scope :for, lambda {|id| 
  {
    :joins => :opinion,
    :conditions => {
      :opinion => { :id => id }
    }
  }
}

named_scope :agreed, :conditions => { :agree => true }
named_scope :with_profiles, :includes => :profile
```

**3.0**

```
scope :agreed, where(:agree => true)

def self.for(id)
  joins(:opinion).where(:opinion => { :id => id })
end
```

In either case you can call `for(id)` on the `OpinionRatings` model and pass it an id:

**2.3**

```
@ratings = OpinionRating.agreed.for(params[:id]).with_profiles
@profiles = @ratings.collect(&:profile)
```

**3.0**

```
@ratings = OpinionRating.agreed.for(params[:id]).includes(:profile)
@profiles = @ratings.collect(&:profile)
```

The upshot of all this is that you can now easily paginate:

```
@ratings = @ratings.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

---

Update for Rails 4.x: more or less the same:

```
scope :agreed, ->{ where agreed: true }

def self.for(id)
  joins(:opinion).where(opinion: { id: id })
end
```

Although for newer Rails my preference is [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) for pagination:

```
@ratings = @ratings.page(params[:page])
```

Comment: Well, the associations are table Opinion has_many :opinion_ratings, and belongs_to :opinion. An opinion is liked to the Profile table through a many-to-many relationship with a join table called Categories. With this set up do you know how it would change the code you mentioned above?

Comment: @Brian I've updated my example, but I can't be certain unless you show me your model classes.

Comment: Adam, how I get at the opinion rating model? If I'm understanding this right Profile.with_opinion returns a list of all the profiles with the specified id? What I need is to get a list of profiles from the OpinionRating model, which belongs_to :opinion and Opinion has_many :opinion_ratings. The Profile model is linked to the Opinion model through the Categories join table.

Comment: This is why I was using an array, because I was unsure how to query the database.

Comment: Well, I appreciate the help, but I think I found the answer to my question. Not sure if it is the most efficient way, but it works. I'm going to look into named_scope some more and try to implement that in the future.

Comment: @Brian it's very difficult to help you if you're not upfront about your model relationships. You should be posting that code along with the question.

Comment: sometimes array can not be avoided ... some filters or orderings are only possible using ruby

Comment: @gorn Unless there is something terribly wrong with his DB structure (and I'm not ruling that out) I am 99% certain this is not one of those cases.

Comment: @AdamLassek it seems to me as well, but he may only be giving an example. I am trying to avoid arrays in these constructs whenever pissoble, but from my experience in 10% of cases I can not avoid arrays. This is just to say, that there are these cases.

Comment: @AdamLassek is it possible to update this answer for Rails 4? It is very in-depth, and would like to know if there are any differences with Rails 4 usage

Comment: @onebree sure, although the API for this has been pretty stable since 3.x. I added an example of an alternative pagination library that I like better.

Comment: @Adam I find that `will_paginate` still works for Rails 4. Besides it not being as well maintained, why do you recommend Kaminari?

Comment: @onebree Kaminari does pretty much the same things with far less complexity than will_paginate. Some people might depend on some of that complexity, but I never have and I appreciate the relative simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

The gem `will_paginate` will paginate both ActiveRecord queries and arrays.

```
list = OpinionRating.where(:opinion_id => params[:id]).includes(:profile).paginate(:page => params[:page])
@agree_list = list.map(&:profile)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the config file or are having trouble with it, you can also just ensure you return an ActiveRecord::Relation instead of an array.  For instance, change the agree_list to be a list of user ids instead, then do an IN on those ids to return a Relation.

```
def agree_list
  list = OpinionRating.find_all_by_opinion_id(params[:id])
  @agree_id_list = []
  list.each do |r|
    user = Profile.find(r.profile_id)
    @agree_id_list << user.id
  end
  @agree_list = User.where(:id => @agree_id_list) 
end
```

This is inefficient from a database perspective, but it's an option for anybody having issues with the will_paginate config file.

Answer (score 0):

I took advantage of rails associations, and came up with a new method:

```
def agree_list
  o = Opinion.find(params[:id])
  @agree_list = o.opinion_ratings(:conditions => {:agree => true}, :order => 'created_at DESC').paginate :page => params[:page]
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to(profile_opinion_path(session[:user]))
end
```

In my view I looked up the profile like so:

```
<% @agree_list.each do |rating| %>
  <% user = Profile.find(rating.profile_id) %>
<% end %>
```

Please post up if there's a better way to do this. I tried to use the named_scope helper in the OpinionRating model with no luck. Here's an example of what I tried, but doesn't work:

```
named_scope :with_profile, lambda {|id| { :joins => [:profile], :conditions => ['profile_id = ?', id] } }
```

That seemed like the same as using the find method though.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using rails 3 ruby 1.9.2. Also, I am just starting app, so no css or styles included.

**Install will_paginate:**

gem install will_paginate

Add to Gemfile and run bundle.

**Controller**

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
    include StructHelper

    def show
        @myData =structHelperGet.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end

end
```

module StructHelper queries a service, not a database.
structHelperGet() returns an array of records.

Not sure if a more sophisticated solution would be to fake a model, or to grab the data every so often and recreate a sqllite table once in a while and have a real model to query. Just creating my first rails app ever.

**View**

```
<div id="Data">
                <%= will_paginate @myData%>
                    <table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>col 1</th>
                    <th>Col 2</th>
                    <th>Col 3</th>
                    <th>Col 4</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    </tbody>
                    <% @myData.each do |app| %>
                        <tr>
                           <td><%=app[:col1]%> </td>
                           <td><%=app[:col2]%> </td>
                           <td><%=app[:col3]%> </td>
                           <td><%=app[:col4]%> </td>
                        </tr>

                    <% end %>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                <%= will_paginate @myData%>
                </div>
```

This will give you pagnation of the default 30 rows per page.

If you have not read http://railstutorial.org yet, start reading it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement pagination even without any gem.I saw this [How do I paginate an Array?](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes#-how-do-i-paginate-an-array). Simple implementation in kaminari gems doc. Please see the below example which i got from kaminari gems doc

```
arr = (1..100).to_a
page, per_page = 1, 10
arr[((page - 1) * per_page)...(page * per_page)] #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
page, per_page = 2, 10
arr[((page - 1) * per_page)...(page * per_page)] #=> [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```