# Pagination in static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, yaml

I have an excel sheet / Yaml file containing few records.
I was wondering if rails provide a way to achieve pagination while reading data from yaml document or excel sheet.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) gem.
You can paginate through any kind of Array-ish object using [Kaminari::PaginatableArray](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/models/array_extension.rb)

```
> p Kaminari::PaginatableArray.new([*1..100]).page(3).per(20)
[41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good pagination gem is [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki)

It works really well with active record relations, and will also paginate arrays as long as you require the right file first. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407304/441979