# Is that possible to use paginate with Acts_as_follower?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@users = User.find_by_username(params[:username]).all_following.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

This calculation won't work:(
I'd like to use pagination and order sort with acts_as_follower.

Comment: What do you mean with "this calculation won't work"?

Comment: @Emrah Thanks for reply. I tried to use that code in my controller but it says error  undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x0000001d2a8f10>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the order (and any other option `ActiveRecord#all` accepts) directly to `all_following` like this

```
@users = User.find_by_username(params[:username]).all_following(:order => 'created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
```

**UPDATE**: will_paginate can paginate an array but you have to tell Rails to include this part as it's not included by default, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407304/1856239).

Comment: I tried your code but it says undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x0000001d1dce10>

Comment: Thanks but it still says undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x0000001c77b9d0>

Comment: My bad. I'm using kaminari for pagination

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

```
@users = User.find_by_username(params[:username]).all_following.sort_by{|i| i.created_at}
Kaminari.paginate_array(@users).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

OR

Mix with Ahmad's answer

```
@users = User.find_by_username(params[:username]).all_following(order: 'created_at DESC')
Kaminari.paginate_array(@users).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

ref: [acts_as_follower github](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower)

ref: [kaminari github](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes)

Comment: I tried your code but it says users_controller.rb:66: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '}'
...owing.sort_by{|i| i.created_at).paginate(page: params[:page])

Comment: there was a typo in sort_by. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks but it says syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_end
...e: params[:page])

Comment: Thanks but it still says undefined method `current_page' for #<Array:0x0000001c63e248>..... Is there something wrong with my view? I coded  like this <%= paginate @users %>