# Is it possible to use pagination with acts_as_follower?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

This calculation won't work:(
I'd like to use pagination and order sort with `acts_as_follower`.
If anyone knows how to handle it, please tell me how.

I'm using `kaminari` for pagination now. Please  let me knof if I need to add something else.

### In my `Controller`

```
@users = User.find_by_username(params[:username]).all_following.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

### View

```
<%= paginate @users, :window => 4, :outer_window => 5, :left => 2, :right => 2 %>
```

Comment: What's **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936091/is-that-possible-to-use-paginate-with-acts-as-follower)**?

Comment: First describe your problem in the First line...There is no head or Tail in your question...

Comment: @jdoe Sorry about that. Previous question went so long, and some info has got changed so I re-created new question here