# will_paginate and .sort =>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, will-paginate

I recently got the will_paginate gem installed and it works great, but I would like it to work with the setup I currently have. Right now I show all feeds (or posts) on the same page, but they are sorted after how many people clicked on that page:

controller.rb

```
 @t = Time.now
 @h1 = @t - 1.hour
 @feeds = Feed.find(:all, :order => "created_at DESC").sort { |p1, p2| p2.impressionist_count(:filter=>:all, :start_date=>@h1) <=> p1.impressionist_count(:filter=>:all, :start_date=>@h1)}
```

Now... I tested the paginate gem and it works fine if I do this in the controller:

controller.rb

```
 @feeds = Feed.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC")
```

So I thought 1+1=2 and tried to combine the two by doing:

controller.rb

```
@feeds = Feed.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page=>params[:page], :order => "created_at DESC").sort { |p1, p2| p2.impressionist_count(:filter=>:all, :start_date=>@h1) <=> p1.impressionist_count(:filter=>:all, :start_date=>@h1)}
```

I'm not able to sort my posts and paginate them. I get an error when I try to load the page:

undefined method `total_pages' for #

I would like this to work, it would be pretty sweet :). However, if it does not work, is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails will\_paginate an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because will_paginate works by default only on ActiveRecord relationships. Once you use the sort, it's converted to an array. If you want will_paginate to work with an array, you'll need to require support for it in your controller.

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```