# Will_Paginate Gem With Rails Displaying Results In Wrong Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, will-paginate

Attempting to sort an entry by an associated field, unfortunately when paginating with Will Paginate the sorting is wrong.

```
@categories = Category.includes(:posts)
.page(params[:page])
.order("posts.post_at DESC")
```

I have tried many variations, but unfortunately will paginate does not seem to respect the sort order of categories.  Without the pagination the categories are sorted correctly.

How can I get Will Paginate to respect the order?

The end goal is Categories sorted by posts.post_at and paginated while maintaining that order.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried swapping `.page` and `.order`? Otherwise you are only sorting the current page. So: `@categories = Category.includes(:posts).order("posts.post_at DESC").page(params[:page])`

Comment: Yes, in fact that is what I tried initially until reading a Stack Overflow post stating to do it the other way around.  The result is the same - Categories do not sort by post_at.

Comment: Another variation I actually tried was:
`categories = Category.includes(:posts).order("posts.post_at DESC")
@categories = categories.page(params[:page])`

Still had the same result.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552999/will-paginate-and-sort)?

Comment: I had not, but tested the require 'will_paginate/array' addition, and there was no effect.

Comment: I did check the class, and the class is not an array, but an ActiveRecord relation which explains why the require statement makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@categories = Category.includes(:posts).order("posts.post_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Comment: Tried, unfortunately same result.  Categories do not order by the post_at attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't comment due to low rep, but what are you trying to sort by and what do you want listed?

If you want categories in a certain order with the associated posts, is that by alphabetical?

`@categories = Category.includes(:posts).order('categories.name??').page(params[:page])`

Category with most recent posts?

`@categories = Category.includes(:posts).order("posts.post_at DESC").page(params[:page])`

Or are you wanting the most recent posts with the categories listed along with it?

`@posts = Post.includes(:category).order('posts.post_at DESC').page(params[:page])`

It's unclear what your end goal is with this query.

Comment: Hello, the end goal is Categories sorted by posts.post_at .  Thanks for your comment I will update original question.

Comment: is that by only the most recent post_at?

Comment: Yes.. the sort order works fine simply with `@categories = Category.includes(:posts).order("posts.post_at DESC")` but with pagination the order is ignored.

Comment: do you have a default scope for your `Category` model?