# How to match two kind of records on a third table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've 5 tables :

```
**areas**
id
otherfields

**realtors**
id
otherfields

**users**
id
otherfields

**areas_realtors**
area_id
realtor_id

**areas_users**
area_id
user_id
```

My relation in models are :

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :realtors
end

class AreasRealtor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :realtor
  belongs_to :area
end

class AreasUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :area
end

class Realtor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :areas
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :areas
end
```

In my "realtor controller", i need to select all the users with common areas with the realtor.

I don't found the solution with Active Record or with "simple MySQL query"...

Thanks for advance,

F.

Comment: Is there a reason you've split `Areas` into three models? Seems to me that you'd only want one `Area` model and then have Area belong_to both `:realtor` and `:user`.

Comment: @settheline : Realtors and Users models are Devise models. Areas is another model used on few fonctionnalities

Comment: That's fair, but I'm wondering about the these two models: `AreasRealtor`, `AreasUser`. Those seem to be adding unneeded complexity to your associations. Are they necessary or could you do what I suggested above and only have one `Area` model? You'd still have your separate Devise models for `Realtor` and `User`.

Comment: @settheline i've the 2 models because each realtor and users have many areas

Comment: Right, but are they the same areas? From your associations it looks like they are....If that's the case, you don't need those two models. You only need one `Area` model.

Comment: but how associate many areas to many users and many realtors ?

Comment: `User has_many :areas`, `Realtor has_many :areas`, `Area belongs_to :user` and `Area belongs_to :realtor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you,... Of cause "just" ruby solution but working.

```
@realtor.areas.collect(&:users).inject(&:+).uniq
```

The `collect` method returns an array including the return values of the called method `users` which always returns an array with the associated users. The `inject` method calls the `+` method on all the collected arrays to add them up to one array. The `uniq` methods removes double User objects from the array. So it returns an array including all User objects that are related to the areas associated with `@relator`.

Comment: I like this solution it seems work but it doesnt work with will_paginate (.paginate(:page => params[:page])...
Do you have an idea of solution ?

Comment: it works now ! i found the solution on this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array

Answer (score 1):

This isn't 100% complete, but I think it gets you on the right track..

It eliminates some unnecessary complexity. Basically realtor is just an extension of a user record in the user's table.

I would do something like this:

```
**areas**
id
otherfields

**users**
id
otherfields

**realtors**
id
user_id
otherfields

**user_areas**
area_id
user_id
```

My relation in models are :

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class UserArea < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user
  has_many :area
end

class Realtor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :areas
  has_one :realtor
end
```

By going with this structure, it allows you to do things like

`User.areas`
`Realtor.user.areas` or if you use `delegate`, you can do `Realtor.areas`.

Then to ultimately get what you're asking for, you could just do `Realtor.joins(:users).where(:area_id => 1)`

Comment: No,it want works. I need "links" on Realtor to Areas

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer in SQL query :

```
select * from users where id IN (select distinct user_id from areas_users where area_id IN (select `area_id` from areas_realtors WHERE realtor_id='86'))
```

If it's possible i would like use an activerecord syntax...