# undefined local variable or method `scoped' for #<Listing::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000725f718>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I get this error when i did pagination (will_paginate) + rails 4. really dont understand what went wrong

gem file

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
```

here is the controller

```
@users = User.where.not(:name => "admin").all
@user_paginate = @users.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
```

view

```
<%= will_paginate @user_paginate %>
```

application controller i did

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

model relations

User `has_many :listings`

Listing `belongs_to :user`

any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Seems like the problem with the associations.Please post your models with associations.

Comment: is there any kind of scope in the model ?

Comment: no there is not any scope in model

Answer (score 5):

found the solution

change `gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'`

to

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'
```

and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try this `@users = User.where.not(:name => "admin").all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)` and see if you get the same error.
or (name: 'admin')

why do you have the require 'will_paginate/array'
thats for something like this array.paginate(:page => a, :per_page => b)

[Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array)