# How do pagination on hash that have value in form of array using Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I have hash that have values in form of array. i am using will paginate for pagination. But recieve error

```
           "undefined method paginate for Hash".
```

below is my code

```
   h = {"127.1.0"=>[31.553965003401203, 74.35798642106394], "127.2.0"=>[54.99947245294339, 74.35810745776595], "127.0.0"=>[51.07178714109552, 71.86443937665145]}

   h.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30) #giving error
```

Any help to done this...

Comment: Have you tried `will_paginate(h)`?   It looks like (from the (docs)[https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation]) that you can paginate collections (non ActiveRecord) objects that way.  I'm not sure what the links will give you since the hash doesn't have an implicit "link" generator.  But that might work.

Comment: Not working for me..................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can use the `will_paginate/array` module which would at least get you paginating on an array.  Try something like this.

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
h = {"127.1.0"=>[31.553965003401203, 74.35798642106394], "127.2.0"=>[54.99947245294339, 74.35810745776595], "127.0.0"=>[51.07178714109552, 71.86443937665145] }
h.keys.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
```

(similar to [Ruby on Rails will_paginate an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array))