# Rails use will_paginate with combined query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

In my application I have a customers model that has many payments and invoices.

```
# customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :payments
  has_many :invoices
end

# payment.rb
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

# invoice.rb
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

In the customers show template I am combining all Invoices and Payments and storing them in the @transactions instance variable.

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    payments = Payment.where(customer: @customer)
    invoices = Invoice.where(customer: @customer)
    @transactions = payments + invoices
  end
```

I want to paginate @transactions using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). Doing this doesn't work:

```
@transactions.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This Answer will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way is to create a third Table of Transactions with polymorphic association as transactionable. And paginate over transactions.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

First Learn polymorphic association

```
 class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :transactionable, polymorphic: true
 end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :transactions, as: :transactionable
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :transactionable
end
```

Other way which is not good to paginate both or use paginate array.

Comment: I am new to rails. Can you provide resources where I can learn how to do this.