# Pagination on ruby array without sending request to controller

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a array of arrays in my `rails` application and it is something like:

`@array=[[1, "Mr.X", "developer"], [2, "Mr.Y", "python"]...... [n, "Mr.Z", "ba"]]`

I am getting these records on runtime from a different database server by using `SQL` query not from `ActiveRecord`. I want to perform **pagination** on this data and I am using `will_paginate/array`

```
@array = @array.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 1)
```

and in my view, I am calling it by:

```
<%= will_paginate @array%>
```

It is showing me the data of one record for the first page and links for other pages, however when clicked on next page link, it is giving the error for `nil:nil class`, as it is again submitting the parameters but this time, the parameters are not appropriate.

**I have the final records in @array and I don't want to send the request in backend again and again and I just want to process it on front end only**.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am having different issue, while submitting the form on the post method for first time, my params are

`params = <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EEzvZTAdFAGZ1vOvfeQ/hx7BmDFknC+xHpP4HdhIUncfZDobL1le1vzeanLRdgVFQtKYLGPCgKOfqf5J9+4J2Q==", "check_box_array"=>["ID", "NAME", "ROLE"], "column_value"=>{"ID"=>"", "NAME"=>"", "ROLE"=>""}, "table_name"=>"employee", "column_length"=>"3", "commit"=>"Search", "controller"=>"test", "action"=>"index"}`

and here on the controller index action I am running SQL query and fetching data from database not using any model and storing the results into array, which I am passing to view like `  <%= will_paginate @array %>

But while clicking on any page number, it is submitting the parameters as `<ActionController::Parameters {"page"=>"2", "controller"=>"test", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>`

and this time, it is not having any query parameters and it is generating the error for nil class

`undefined method for nil:NilClass`

But I don't want to send the query parameters, I just want to show the data of `@array` using pagination i.e. on every page just the required data.

Comment: If you don't want to send the request to the backend again, you can load the entire array once and paginate on the frontend using javascript. ([Here's an example](https://blog.fedecarg.com/2011/10/09/javascript-retrieve-and-paginate-json-encoded-data/))

Comment: use js plugins like datatable then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails will\_paginate an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array)