# Will Paginate Gem: providing custom number of pages instead of active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have used Elastic Search to fetch the data and am trying to use Pagination gem to toggle between pages. But i am currently facing an issue in

```
<%= will_paginate @data %>
```

i am getting an error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007fdcfbd3f128>
```

since @data is an array instead of an Active Record since the data was fetched from Elastic Search

Is there anyway to specify the total pages so that i will still be able to use the gem.

Comment: Using will paginate for array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array   https://makandracards.com/makandra/13521-will_paginate-can-paginate-plain-ruby-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Your @data is an array instead of collection so to use `will_paginate` on array you can do like this:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

And then:

```
@data.paginate(:page => 2, :per_page => 10)
```

will work.

Source: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Backwards-incompatibility#willpaginatecollection