# Pagination for partial array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

My application retrieves items from remote source something like that:

```
# in the controller
@items = RemoteSource(params[:page])
```

The `@items` is an array but just the part of whole collection. 
And I'm trying to paginate it:

```
# in the view
paginate @items
```

Of course it doesn't work.

How I can paginate my collection in such situation?

P.S. I'm using gem [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)

Comment: Search first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529684/rails-paginate-existing-array-of-activerecord-results , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352895/ruby-on-rails-will-paginate-an-array , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545990/rails-3-kaminari-pagination-for-an-simple-array (surely one or more contains the answers you are looking for, and links the the documentation/API)

Comment: Is `@items` an array? You can use the helper `paginate_array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Kaminari helper for this: `@books = Kaminari.paginate_array(@items).page(params[:page])`